# inserir sequencia de data em sequencia no banco

Tags: php

Gostaria de quando inserir a data no for ele somar + 1 dia e inserir novamente.

Tenho este script mas ele me retorna data aleatória:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");

$data = '2017-01-02';  
$data_fim='2017-01-09';

echo '<br />';
//faz a repeticao
for($i = 0; $i < $data_fim; $i++)
{
    // Soma 1 DIA

    echo $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($i . " days", strtotime($data)));

    echo '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
```

tipo assim:

```
2017-01-02  
2017-01-03  
2017-01-05  
2017-01-08  
2017-01-12  
2017-01-17  
2017-01-23  
2017-01-30  
2017-02-07  
2017-02-16  
2017-02-26  
2017-03-09  
2017-03-21  
2017-04-03  
2017-04-17  
2017-05-02  
2017-05-18  
2017-06-04  
2017-06-22  
2017-07-11  
2017-07-31  
2017-08-21
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: obrigado amigo  funcionou !!,

Comment: ele esta gerando data ate ano de 2022 como  queria que fosse da $data inicial ate a $data_fim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concorda que comparar um valor inteiro `$i` com uma string `$data_fim` não faz sentido algum?

Se desejas trabalhar com intervalos de datas, podes utilizar a classe nativa do PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php). Primeiro, definindo as datas de início e fim:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime('2017-01-02'); 
$data_fim = new DateTime('2017-01-09');
```

A classe `DateTime` possui um método chamado `add` para efetuar a adição de datas, aceitando uma instância de [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php) como parâmetro, que definirá o intervalo de tempo que será adicionado. Para definir um período de 1 dia, pode fazer:

```
$interval = new DateInterval("P1D");
```

> O parâmetro `P1D` que é responsável por definir o período. `P` significa `period` e `1D` o intervalo de 1 dia.

Para percorrer as datas, então, basta fazer o loop:

```
for ($i = $data_inicio; $i <= $data_fim; $i->add($interval))
{
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída do programa será:

```
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-07
2017-01-08
2017-01-09
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/G12o/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BhhXcL).

Comment: entendi  obrigado memso""""""""""""""""

Comment: @SergioSilva, se for novo aqui, pode ler o guia de [como e por quê aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/) para saber como marcá-la como aceita. Isso ajudará na organização da comunidade.